# Autofill formular, but constrain one or more cells - Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, autocomplete, google-sheets-formula, autofill

I'm trying to make a google sheets spreadsheet where I calculate the salary for employees based on their hours spent on each project and hourly wage for each project.
Each project pay a different amount. To calculate their salary I need to multiply each hourly wage with the hours spent (for each project) and then sum the amount.

***How to automate this?***
[image]

As seen in the linked image, the hourly wage calculated for each row and then added together.
If I try to autofill this formular by clicking and dragging, the hourly wage values are dragged with the rest, which is wrong.
I want to constrain the hourly wage values and just drag the hours values.
See the next image for what the problem is.

***These values should stay, the others should move:***
[image]

How can I achieve this? Will I have to use other functions or get into custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute reference for `Column B like

```
=$B3*E3+$B4*E4+$B5*E5+$B6*E6
```

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT()` to get result directly without summing manually. Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$6,E3:E6)
```

#### Reference:

- [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you!
Super awesome that you include examples in you answers. Much appreciated.
=SUMPRODUCT is actually best, since I can insert new rows and have them automatically added to the array.

Comment: @CoffeeQuest Glat to know! Then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to mark the thread as solved.